# XAMPP - a way to stop services on clicking Exit?

Tags: xampp

Is there a way to stop all services (Apache,MySql) on clicking "Exit" in the control panel?
So that i don't have to "Stop" them manually every time i am shutting XAMPP down.

Answer (score 0):

XAMPP is not a ready solution. It is always treated as an overlay for working services. The fact, you're shutting down XAMPP Control Panel doesn't mean (for many) that you're shutting down Apache server or MySQL RDBMS as well.

On the contrary, for example I'm closing and re-opening XAMPP Control Panel many times a day and if developers of this tool would attach shutting down my services / servers along with exiting, the I would see it as a huge bug. It is a tiny controlling tool and should not act like this. Try to look at this problem like that: Windows does not shut down all your services once you quite Control Panel, right?

You have many *.bat files in your XAMPP folder for starting up or shutting down particular services. If you would like to have a quick solution, then consider writing a small "close_all.bat" file, where you simply put calls to "apache_stop.bat", "mysql_stop.bat" and other required. Put that *.bat file in your XAMPP folder and get yourself a shortcut to your desktop, placing it next to XAMPP Control Panel shortcut. This way, you'll be able to shut down all your service with just a two click and you won't have to use XAMPP Control Panel at all for this purpose.